# I can't find any errors in this code, does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do?

Tags: c

The code is from an activity that asks me to identify and fix the error, but I really have no idea where there is an error in the code ''Identify the problem and why it can make your code break'' I've already tried everything (I think) and I didn't see any errors, does anyone have a suggestion?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void divide (float n1, float n2) {
                printf ("%f / %f = %f", n1, n2, n1/n2);
}
int main () {
                float n1, n2;
                printf ("Digite o primeiro valor: ");
                scanf ("%f", &n1);
                printf ("Digite o segundo valor: ");
                scanf ("%f", &n2);
                divide  (n1, n2);
}
```

Comment: What happens if I enter `1` then `0`?

Comment: What happens if n2 is 0?

Comment: Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: also try entering "parrot"

Comment: What do you mean by "everything"?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when the denominator `n2` is 0. It won't work, and will give the unexpected output. So, you will have to handle it. such as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void divide (float n1, float n2) {
    if (n2 == 0){
        printf("can not divide by 0");
    }
    else{
        printf ("%f / %f = %f", n1, n2, n1/n2);
    }
}
```